# Stop my code when pressing keyboard button

Tags: python, pyautogui

my problem is when i press "p" code not stopping. I have to spam "p" for stopping code, probably there is time.sleep and i have to wait for it but i cant wait for it. I want to stop code immediately when i press p. is there any way for it ? there is my code

```
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard
import time
from PIL import Image

button = "p"

def m():
    if pg.locateOnScreen('Screenshot_2.png', confidence = 0.9):
        pc = pg.locateOnScreen('Screenshot_2.png', confidence = 0.9)
        pg.center(pc)
        pg.click(pc)
        print('found!')
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
        print('not found!')
        
        
while True:
    m()
    if keyboard.is_pressed(button):
        print("stopped")
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's checking if the key is pressed in the exact moment that `if` statement is executed. Which is a problem when that loop is spinning so fast. You can use a callback to essentially cache the should stop condition.

```
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard
import time
from PIL import Image

button = "p"

stop = False
def onkeypress(event):
    global stop
    if event.name == button:
        stop = True

def m():
    if pg.locateOnScreen('Screenshot_2.png', confidence = 0.9):
        pc = pg.locateOnScreen('Screenshot_2.png', confidence = 0.9)
        pg.center(pc)
        pg.click(pc)
        print('found!')
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
        print('not found!')
        
      
keyboard.on_press(onkeypress)  
while True:
    m()
    if stop:
        print("stopped")
        break
```

Comment: well it's good but it still wait for ending function. i need something break middle of function.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786918/start-stop-a-while-loop

Comment: @NanoForger did you want the entire program to exit or just to stop `m()` at some point and return control? Because if it's the latter you'll need to put `if` statements at points you'd like it to stop. If you want it to stop at any random arbitrary point that's not exactly something you can do. Moreover, it's absolutely not something you *should* do.

Comment: this is exactly what i need but if it can't be done i have to solve it with if statements. thanks for help